# Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project in ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, bintray

Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/com/afollestad/easyvideoplayer/0.3.0/easyvideoplayer-0.3.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Found this gradle error while app build.
Offline mode is not turned on.

I found that https://dl.bintray.com is not working.
So is there any solution to use an alternative repo to get "bintray" and "easyvideoplayer"

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can download jar file then add it to libs folder

Comment: Could you please tell me, from where I can download the jar file ?

Comment: Or you can clone from https://github.com/ammaoui/easy-video-player

Comment: I really appreciate your valuable help, and I would to like to tell you that, this repo uses the same gradle dependency from Jcenter. So even if I clone this repo, I might face the same issue that I'm facing right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    compile group: 'com.github.ravenfeld', name: 'easyvideoplayer', version: '1.2.1'
```